# Maven custom plugin error

Tags: maven

I just created a custom plugin using the archetype as described here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

I can compile the plugin, but I can't run the goal. What am I doing wrong?

```
/**
* Goal which touches a timestamp file.
*
* @deprecated Don't use!
*/
@Mojo(name = "touch", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PROCESS_SOURCES)
public class MyMojo
       extends AbstractMojo {

   public void execute()
           throws MojoExecutionException {        
       getLog().warn("Just a test");
   }
```

}

Here is the usage example of the Mojo (in a different almost empty project):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>                             
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

On the commandline I run: **mvn sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:touch**

And I get this error:

Plugin sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Maven version is: Apache Maven 3.3.3

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seemed to be having some download issues from central or from your repository (firewall/proxy)...please post the full output of your build...I assume there are warnings at the beinning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says maven cannot locate your plugin artifact

After building your plugin , your plugin jar will be placed in your local repository. Check your local repo for this jar

```
sample\plugin\hello-maven-plugin\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\hello-maven-plugin-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In the example version is `1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: The artifact is actually there. When I run the command with a non existent artifact, like so mvn Xsample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:touch" it will tell me  "Error resolving version for plugin 'Xsample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin' from the repositories".

Comment: While using the custom plugin if you put different version than the plugin version in local repo , you will get the said exception , like if you use      <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: Indeed. I haven't realized I had 1.0-SNAPSHOT but referenced 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. My bad.